# Template can not be resolved to a type

Tags: java, android

I have this code in an android project, which I am working on, where SomeService refers to SomeService.template.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SomeService.class);
bindService(intent, conn, 0);
```

when I run my code, however, I become this error:

> "SomeService can not be resolved to a type. - Java Problem"

This code was not written by me. I need it for farther use, but I can not even test, if it does, what it's supposed to be doing. 
Where should I look for an error?

Comment: could you please add more code. (i.e. the SomeService  class) ?

Comment: Do you import the SomeService class? import yourPackage.SomeService;?

Comment: I can not import it. it says that the SomeService can not be resolved to a type also. the class is somehow not found, although it is in the same package as the other classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by renaming .template to .java-

It works for now. I don't know if it'll be an issue later on.

(So, I don't know how I should mark this question as answered, since none of the above have helped me, to accept them.)

Answer (score 0):

Please check

- is SomeService a class, not an interface
- is SomeService accessable  public
- is SomeService published in Manifest

Comment: yes, it's a class which extends Service.
It's public
Manifest says:
<service
            android:name=".SomeService"
            android:process=":backer" >
        </service>

Answer (score 0):

Restart Eclipse. Press ctrl+shift+O in order to resolve the issue.